# Chrome Ignoring Host File

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser

I am having issues with Chrome and IE.

They are ignoring the Windows hostfile. When I ping the website URL using cmd prompt, it return with the correct IP as per the host file, however when i visit that said URL on chrome, it is going via DNS and not the host file.

Any suggestions on how I could fix this? I have tried clearing caches, flushing DNS etc. This is only happening on one pc, not multiple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you behind a proxy ? The below discussion would help :

https://superuser.com/questions/30197/how-do-i-get-ie-to-use-my-hosts-file-when-using-a-proxy-pac-file

Comment: Seems like that is exactly the issue! Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: If it helps , you can accept the answer and close it.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean "hosts" file?

In Chrome go to `chrome://net-internals/#sockets` then click "Flush socket pools", from https://www.askmehelpdesk.com/chrome/how-can-set-chrome-use-local-dns-hosts-file-831226.html

Comment: lotta answers out there, this one worked for me in July 2019